# Get href value in Splinter?

Tags: python, href, splinter

I would like to get `href` value from `<a>` element in Splinter.

Is there any api method for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are selecting elements using the [find_by_* methods](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_by_css), instances returned by these are [`ElementList`s](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/element-list.html#splinter.element_list.ElementList). After you select the element you are interested in (most probably an [`ElementAPI`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.ElementAPI) instance), access the property like a dictionary:

```
the_element['href']
```

Comment: Too bad `element['href']` returns an absolute URL (at least under Firefox), not the actual property, as in HTML, which may be relative.

Answer (score 1):

```
#simplest possible working example demonstrating this in action
import splinter
b = splinter.Browser()
b.visit("http://www.google.com")
elems = b.find_by_tag("a")
for e in elems:
    print(e["href"])
```