# Get HTML attributes using splinter

Tags: python, splinter

Using splinter is there a simple way to get access to the HTML attributes of a WebDriverElement

```
>>> from splinter import Browser
>>> 
>>> browser = Browser('firefox')
>>> browser.visit('http://lovdtest.mcri.edu.au/individuals/00000143')
>>> imgs =  browser.find_by_tag('img')
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x1de2610>, <splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x1de2690>]
```

I can get individual attributes by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816397/get-href-value-in-splinter) (eg, `imgs[0]['src']`, `imgs[0]['alt']`) but there does not seem to be a keys() or items() method implemented in the WebDriverElement class.

`imgs[0].__dict__` contains values that are unrelated to the HTML attributes.
    {'action_chains': , '_element': , 'parent': }

What can I do to get a dictionary with information on the HTML attributes of imgs[0]?

```
{"src": "gfx/header1.png", "alt": "Logo", "width": "172",
"height": "31", "id": "site_logo", "style": 
"margin-top : 5px; cursor : pointer;"}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this is possible (I've looked at all the attributes). Perhaps this should be a feature request to splinter...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
imgs =  browser.find_by_tag('img')
for image in imgs:
    image._element.get_attribute('id')
```

Comment: You could use `image.__getitem__('id')` instead.

Use of private (single underscore-prefixed) methods is discouraged, since they should be considered non-public: _"[...] internal interfaces (packages, modules, classes, functions, attributes or other names) should still be prefixed with a single leading underscore."_ https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id50

Answer (score 0):

From the [Splinter API Docs](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.ElementAPI):

> Any element in the page can be represented as an instance of ElementAPI.
> Once you have an instance, you can easily access attributes like a dict:
>
> ```py
> element = browser.find_by_id("link-logo").first
> assert element['href'] == 'https://splinter.readthedocs.io'
> ```

This might be a new addition since the question was originally asked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).